# Differentiability of a curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My question is that is there any formal definition of the word 'curve' in mathematics ?

If there is, does it say anything about the differentiability of a curve?

The question arises from a question I was asked in an exam:
Find a curve passing through $(0,a)$ and $(b,0)$ . such that when it is revolved around the x axis, the surface has minimum surface area.

An answer I came up with was an 'L' shape connecting $(0,a)$ , the origin and $(b,0)$  as it has zero surface area.

Comment: You are aware that rotation of that curve gives you a disk and a line segment as cylinder of radius zero? And that the disk has a positive surface?

Comment: I didn't notice that at all! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

From Simon&Blumes 'Mathematics for economists' a curve is defined as follows:

> Definition: A curve in $\Bbb R^n$ is an n-tuple of continuous functions
>
> $x(t) = (x_1(t),...,x_n(t))$

Since not every continuous function is differentiable: no, it does not necessarily say something about that.

Comment: In other peoples opinions this is a path and a curve as geometric object is the image of a path. Different paths may provide different parametrizations of the same curve.